# ajax post error chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm looking to send my form details through ajax, but every time I hit Submit button, I get the error

```
 POST http://192.***.**.***:****/api/csl net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT


 m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ index.html:278
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
m.event.trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:3
m.extend.each @ jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.m.each @ jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.extend.trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
m.each.m.fn.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ index.html:223
m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

and

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input on index line :1
```

Here's the code where I'm having issues

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            //contentType: "application/x-www-from-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            url: 'http://192.***.**.***:**/api/csl',
            data: source,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("in ajax");
                var resultsList = data;
                var source = $('#renderCalculation').html();
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                calcTable.html(template(resultsList));
                $('#tblCalc td:nth-child(2)').each(function(d, e) {
                    $(e).text("$" + parseFloat($(this).text()).formatMoney(2)); 
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

i got error from browser side

Comment: I'm confused, are you expecting to get back JSON or HTML here? Also, if the connection timed out, the server never responded and closed the connection ?

Comment: The first error you show, is that being reported from your server or from the browser? What does your server say happened?

Comment: I think somewhere in your js there's a typo. Can we see the whole js file?

Comment: i did this code in html file and while debugging i come to know that problem is in ajax function

Comment: The thing is, your ajax code looks good yet the error tells there's a syntax error somewhere (the fact that it's on line 1makes me think that you forgot a closing bracket or semicolon). Try removing the whole ajax thing and see if you still find the error in the console.

Comment: i did change it location ...first it was inside another function now its out side and now it throws error of  Uncaught ReferenceError: source is not defined

Comment: still the same errors that were before

Comment: if i remove all ajax part then there are no errors in console

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other error, You're leftover a });